# Xamarin iOS warning - IAVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a warning asking to use a different overload for the SetSampleBufferDelegate method, but no overload exists that takes a `IAVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`.  Can someone direct me on how to correct this please?  Is there another library with extension methods that is missing?

**warning CS0618:** 'AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.SetSampleBufferDelegate(AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, DispatchQueue)' is obsolete: 'Use overload accepting a IAVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this change was introduced not to long ago. For your own refernce you can find the api change information [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/api_changes/ios_10.4.0_to_10.8.0/).

That being said, I can't see any references to this being added into Xamarin's monotouch framework as of yet. So unless this is throwing a runtime exception I would likely just make note of it, and not worry too much for the time being.

It is possible that it will be added into a later version of xamarin.ios when they release upcoming updates.

It is also worth noting that apples documentation doesn't/hasn't marked AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate as deprecated. [See here for confirmation of this.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureaudiodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate)